# How can I get _analyze results and _search results in one request while using Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer

I want to highlight search results in the front-end with JavaScript. So I need to all analyzed tokens of the search query.

Now I am using both the two APIs _analyze and _search with two requests.

Is there any way to do this in a single request?

Comment: No. But you can use highlighting in a search request.

Comment: Yes. I know that. But I don't want to store the whole data in Elasticsearch.